# Hive on S3 multi aws users and Spark

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, emr

This is my scenario

I am a  spark and aws enthusiast and I am itching to understand more about the technology.

Case 1:  My spark application runs on an EMR cluster and the spark application 
read from a hive on s3 table and write into a hive table on s3. In this case , the S3 buckets belong to the same user usera  so I added  fs.s3.awsAccessKeyId  and fs.s3.awsSecretAccessKey to a config file . In my case I added it to the hdfs-site.xml. usera had the right permissions to access the bucket so no problem .

Case 2: I am reading from 2 hive tables on s3.  table1 and table2.
table1 belongs to user1 and table2 belongs to user2.

given that i cannot specify multiple awsAccessKeyId in the config file for s3. [ I understand that s3a has a concept of bucket specific keys but I am not using s3a I am using s3.]

how are these scenarios supported in aws EMR ?

I understand that IAM , EC2  instance role and profile role can apply here

Answer (score 1):

I think the solution to your problem is [cross-account permissions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/example-walkthroughs-managing-access-example2.html). Thus, you can define permission for user1 to access user2's bucket. You can also take a look at [this](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/tutorial_cross-account-with-roles.html) too.

Answer (score 0):

Apache Hadoop 2.8 supports per-bucket configuration. AWS EMR doesn't, which is something you will have to take up with them.

As a workaround, you can put secrets in the URI, e.g. s3://user:secret@bucket, remembering to encode special characters in the secret. After doing that, the URL, logs and stack traces must be considered sensitive data and not shared.

Comment: thanks .  I have some issues with your solution .  How is that not a security hole and could you share an example of encoding special characters.

Comment: yeah I definitely have security concerns about adding the credentials being included in the S3 URI . That is a  big security hole .

Comment: I was kind of surprised to discover people were doing it; tried as hard as I could to strip the secrets from all logs, but it's hard to stop. Hadoop 2.8 tells people off for doing this and warns it may be stopped in future. It's just prior to per-bucket config, it was the only way to use multiple credentials

Comment: regarding encoding. I think you use %2f for + or similar. I don't recall the details, as I never use this mechanism myself. It's too dangerous to use for anything but troubleshooting. One problem we have there is that the auth code deliberately doesn't log anything useful precisely for those security reasons....